# Haskell: Stack overflow when finding max on a large list

Tags: performance, haskell, stack-overflow, lazy-evaluation

I have the following implementation of [problem 1-4 of the Matasano Cryptopals Challenge](http://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/4/), to find one line in a file that is a text string xor'd with a single byte. It works well enough for large files, but displays "Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes." for the file provided.

```
import System.IO
import System.Environment
import Control.Monad
import Data.Bits
import Data.Word
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List hiding (maximumBy)
import Data.Char
import Data.Ord
import Data.Foldable hiding (sum)


hexChars = "0123456789ABCDEF"

hexToBytes :: String -> Maybe [Word8]
{- Converts a hex string into a byte array -}

hexToBytes hexes = hexToBytes' (map toUpper hexes)
hexToBytes' (char1 : char2 : xs) = do
    tail <- hexToBytes' xs
    byte1 <- char1 `elemIndex` hexChars
    byte2 <- char2 `elemIndex` hexChars
    return ((fromIntegral(byte1*16 + byte2) :: Word8) : tail)
hexToBytes' [_] = Nothing
hexToBytes' [] = Just []

maxBy :: Ord b => Foldable f => (a -> b) -> f a -> a
maxBy = maximumBy . comparing

bytesToString :: Integral i => Monad m => m i -> m Char
bytesToString = liftM (chr . fromIntegral)  

isLowercase x = (x >= 'a') && (x <= 'z')

asciiCheck :: Word8 -> Int
asciiCheck x = if (isLowercase . chr . fromIntegral) x then 1 else 0

score = (sum . map asciiCheck)

readLines :: Handle -> IO [String]
readLines handle = do
    eof <- hIsEOF handle
    if eof then
        return []
    else liftM2 (:) (hGetLine handle) (readLines handle)

decode key = map (xor key)

keys = [minBound ..] :: [Word8]

massDecode inputs =
    maxBy score (liftM2 decode keys inputs)

main = do
    hSetEncoding stdout latin1
    args <- getArgs
    handle <- case args of
        [] -> return stdin
        (x:xs) -> openFile x ReadMode
    lines <- readLines handle
    putStrLn $ bytesToString $ massDecode $ catMaybes $ map hexToBytes lines
```

The program works by traversing a list containing every input line xor'd with every possible key. I suspect that this large list is responsible for the overflow somehow, but I assumed that this would not cause memory issues because the list would be generated lazily. I don't think I have a firm enough understanding of when thunks are evaluated to intuit how this is causing a stack overflow.

So my question is: Why is generating or traversing this list causing a stack overflow?

Comment: yes your code would help - till then maybe you can have a look at [this Wiki article dealing with the different folds and their properties](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl')

Comment: `foldl'` will probably alleviate any space issues...

Comment: Also, be sure you're compiling with optimization (`-O2`).

Comment: @recursion.ninja: I'm using maximumBy for the folding.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: The compiler flag prevents the overflow for the input on the cryptopals site, but still triggers an overflow on input that is only twice as large.

Comment: My Haskell "spidey-sense" tells me that you need enforce strictness after reading the lines from the file...

Comment: Well since someone deleted my answer (admittedly wasn't fleshed out but I was at work and didn't have time to finish it out), there is a good explanation of the issue you're running into [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Stack_overflow)

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.libraries/25602), the `maximumBy` on list that we now have in the prelude isn't optimally performant, for a variety of, well, let's just say "reasons."

If you use the proposed `maximumBy'` function, which is strict, you'll likely fix the leak:

```
foldl1' f l = foldl' f (head l) (tail l)

maximumBy' f = foldl1' max'
  where max' x y = case f x y of
                        GT -> y
                        _  -> x
```